# Rotating movieclip and changing to a particular frame (S.O.S)

Tags: actionscript-3, math, rotation, degrees

i would apreciate if someone help me with some coding.

i have this code that i previously get to rotate a movieclip with the mouse, and get to another frame, for a college work (we only did the tweens, just learned the basic coding) but i cant get no result.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

knob_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, rotate);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, endrotate );
var angle:Number=0

function rotate(e:Event):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,rotate);


    var position:Number = Math.atan2(mouseY - knob_mc.y,mouseX - knob_mc.x);


    angle=(position/Math.PI) *180;
    knob_mc.rotation = angle;

}

function endrotate(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    knob_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, rotate);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, menu);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,rotate);
    knob_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,rotate);
}

function menu(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if ( angle >=1 && angle <= 100 )
    {
        gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
    else if (angle >=100 && angle < 340) {
        gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put the code that adds the event listener for the `rotate` function somewhere outside the `rotate` callback. As it is, it is never being called.

```
function rotate(e:Event):void
{
    var position:Number = Math.atan2(mouseY - knob_mc.y,mouseX - knob_mc.x);
    angle=(position/Math.PI) *180;
    knob_mc.rotation = angle;

}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,rotate);
```

Comment: i did what you told me but this only made the movieclip move with the mouse. I feel i mislead you, the knob_mc rotate when i press and move the mouse but i can't get the AS3 script to make the angle in the If's jump to another frame, do you have any sugestions?

Comment: [link](http://www.fastswf.com/AMrZieU) this was the intended but with the next frame step)